# Stock exchange party calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, math

I'm writing a program (http://dancingrobots.org/beurs/) for my youth club that calculates prices of drinks by the number of times it has been bought in the last round (quite a fun party concept). Now the way I calculate the prices is like this:

```
cola = cola * (vercola / pastVerCola);
```

Where cola is the price
vercola is the times it has been bought this round.
pastVerCola is the times it has been bought last round.

A drink can't go under 0.5 euro and above 10 euro.

My two problems are:

- The prices fluctuation is too high (It mostly chances from max to min
  and reversed)
- If a drink is two times 0 bought, it error's (0/0)

For those intressted here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/PsT2v2Tr

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but may I suggest you use an array for all your drinks? It will be more flexible if you need to add/remove drinks and it will save you 90% of your code.

Comment: Interesting question,  what is the objective of the price?  i.e. should it get cheaper or more expensive the more people who buy it?

Comment: I think the idea is that when a drink is frequently bought, it's price goes up (like the stock market). Then people switch to buying another drink which has fallen to a "bargain" price. Versions I have seen make it more exciting by adding a random market "C_R_A_S_H" every half an hour where all prices suddenly plummet for 5 minutes - accompanied by lots of flashing colours and a siren of course. I think that's what the <marquee> tag was invented for ;)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the concept. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reduce the fluctuation you can use the square root :

```
cola = cola * Math.sqrt(vercola / pastVerCola);
```

Use sqrt multiple times to reduce it even more.

Another way (one I have used in the past) is to dampen fluctuations using a fixed load e.g.

```
cola = cola * (vercola + 50) / (pastVerCola + 50);
```

This is useful because it also lets you have an automatic increase/decrease in price with each round (by using 40, 50, 60, etc.)

You can combine these two effects to get the fluctuation you require. e.g.

```
var VER = 40;     // Constant
var PASTVER = 60; // Constant
cola = cola * Math.sqrt((vercola + VER) / (pastVerCola + PASTVER));
```

By the way, I think the error is caused if no-one buys a particular drink in a round. pastVerCola will be set to zero, giving you a divide by zero error. Using the constants avoids this situation completely.

Comment: You sir or madam, saved a great party.